# Two spaces which are isometrically isomorphism

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $X,Y$ are two spaces which  are isometrically isomorphism, When we say that $X$ is isometrically isomorphic to $Y$, Does it mean that the functional $\phi: X\to Y$ is not onto?

Comment: What is $\phi$?

Comment: No; it actually means that _it is_ onto, i.e., a bijective isometry.

Answer (score 1):

it means that there is a bijection $\phi : X\rightarrow Y$, and also the distance between points is preserved under the mapping, with respect to the two metrics on $X$ and $Y$, so basically this is **stronger** than just isomorphic. (isomorphic is one to one **and** onto)

Comment: Actually isomorphism usually includes the statement that certain structures (like vector space structures) are respected. One to one and onto alone is just a bijection.

Comment: of course, but every isomorphism has to be bijective, and that was in the context of the question.